# Fading out div to reveal a background image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make my jQuery so that the hover fades the span to reveal the `bgSky` div underneath but I can't get it to work. The CSS works but I want to animate it using JavaScript to make it look nicer. Here's the code:

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="mainTbl">
  <div id="bgSky">
    <table id="menu">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><a href=""><span class="genAnchor"><img src="images/physicalArchives.png" class="genImages" style="width:55%;"/></span></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="border"><a href=""><span class="genAnchor"><img src="images/30s.png" class="genImages"/></span></a></td>
        <td><a href=""><span class="genAnchor"><img src="images/40s.png" class="genImages"/></span></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="border"><a href=""><span class="genAnchor"><img src="images/50s.png" class="genImages"/></span></a></td>
        <td><a href=""><span class="genAnchor"><img src="images/60s.png" class="genImages"/></span></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="border"><a href=""><span class="genAnchor"><img src="images/70s.png" class="genImages"/></span></a></td>
        <td><a href=""><span class="genAnchor"><img src="images/80s.png" class="genImages"/></span></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="border"><a href=""><span class="genAnchor"><img src="images/90s.png" class="genImages"/></span></a></td>
        <td><a href=""><span class="genAnchor"><img src="images/00s.png" class="genImages"/></span></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><a href=""><span class="genAnchor"><img src="images/10s.png" class="genImages"/></span></a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
html, body, div, span, table, tr, th, td,article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  background:#C71C2D;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:"Tw Cen MT",sans-serif;
}
h1{
  color:white;
  font-size:240%;
}
#logo{
  height:30px;
  width:298px;
  position:absolute;
  left:30px;
  top:30px;
}
/*-- INDEX SETTINGS --*/
td{
  padding-right:1;
  padding-bottom:1;
}
tr{
  border-top: 1px solid #9ea8a9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9ea8a9;
}
#menu{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.border{
  border-right:1px solid #9ea8a9;
} 
a{
  display:table;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.genAnchor{
  display: table-cell;
  border:1px solid white;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
.genAnchor:hover{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
#mainTbl{
  position:relative;
  width:55%;
  margin:10 auto;
  padding:50px 0 50px;
  height:75%;
  background:white;
}
.genImages{
  height:1in;
  width:2.25in;
}
#bgSky{
  position:relative;
  background-image:url("images/sky.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
  width:70%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

**JS**

```js
$(function(){
  $("td").hover(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(0.5, function(){
      $(this).fadeIn();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You can animate using css too, you know..`but I cant get it to work` what's happen? Can you create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com/) for this?

Comment: `$(this)` will be referring to the `td` and not the `span`. Is that it? You have not described very clearly what issues you are facing with your current approach.

Comment: I'm trying to have it so that the .genAnchor:hover that's in the CSS runs using a fade in jQuery so that it looks nicer than the css which is just switching from transparent to opaque

Comment: You can use transition in css3. Do you know [css3 transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)?

Comment: Not really, I'll look into it right now and see if I can get it to work. Thanks

Comment: As simple as this CSS: `.genAnchor:hover { background: rgba(0,0,0,0); transition: background 1s ease; }`

Comment: Instead of `$(this).fadeOut(0.5,` try `$(this).fadeOut(500,`